# Unable to switch on Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I can't switch on the Bluetooth, nor the visibility. Every button in this page doesn't respond. The only thing I can do is to check the box, but no Bluetooth status is shown.

I checked my /etc/bluetooth/main.conf. `AutoEnable=true`

I also tried commands:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth  #Nothing changed or showed up
```

as well as

```
sudo rmmod btusb  
>rmmod: ERROR: Module btusb is not currently loaded
```

[image]

Edit: adding the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb` as suggested

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [1028:06b9]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350] [1002:6610] (rev 83)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2516:003c  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does it mean I don't have Bluetooth adapter?

Comment: May be bluez is not installed, run this command: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez` then try again

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb`