# No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am new to Ubuntu (and to the whole world of Linux) and am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have completely uninstalled windows and installed Ubuntu on my system. Now when I go to the settings to connect to Bluetooth, this is what it shows me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0tXe.png)

Earlier, when I was using windows, Bluetooth would occasionally cause problems but would work just fine most of the time.

Could someone please help me with this issue as I have my classes going online and have to use my Bluetooth headset.
Thanks in advance for what I know is going to be a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 21.04 and checked
[Unable to switch on Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158879/unable-to-switch-on-bluetooth)
Among others but here's what I did so that I could get my Bluetooth service going and manage with app:

`$ sudo rmmod btusb`

`$ sudo modprobe btusb`

`$ sudo apt install blueman`

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms`

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms`

`$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`

`$ sudo apt-get install blueman`

Then you should have an app you manage any (near) devices available.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
When I give the first command, i.e.
(sudo rmmod btusb)
It gives an error
(rmmod: ERROR: Module btusb is not currently loaded)

Comment: Hi, take a look at [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915235/error-to-load-module-btusb-with-kernel-4-10-0-20-generic) to see if this helps.